# Forcefully save workbook on open with workbook name and current date on desktop

Tags: excel, vba

I need a macro to save the excel sheet whenever opened with workbook name and current date, on desktop.
Also if the same name is there on desktop i.e. workbook name and current date macro should not run (to avoid overwrite).

Please help to edit my below code:

```
Sub SaveInFormat()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Workbooks.Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="I:\CAP_Profile\Desktop\" & Format(Date, "yyyymm") & "DB" & ".xls", leFormat:=51
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to save it when the workbook is opened use the Workbook Open sub:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

End Sub
```

And then for getting the desktop path, use the special folders.

```
Dim path As String
path = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")
```

To check if the file exists on the desktop use something like this (DirFile being a string to the exact path of the file):

```
If Len(Dir(DirFile)) = 0 Then
    ''Go ahead and save it
Else
    End
End If
```

Comment: Thank you Alex. But I am unable to use above code. Can you please help me more to use it as a complete code.

Comment: @ArunYadav, what part of this code are you unable to use?

Comment: I am not unable to find if workbook with same name exist and if yes/No then take required action as mentioned in my below code. Can you please help me to complete my code.

Comment: Workbook_Open :
dirpath = "I:\CAP_Profile\Desktop\Checker Template " & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-d")

'if dirpath exists
    'true then msg you already have a copy saved with todays date, do you want to open that?
        ' if yes then
        'display alert = false
        'open already saved copy and close temp copy
        'Else
        'close temp copy
        'exit sub
        'End If  
    'false then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=dirpath
    Sheets("CHECKER").Activate
    Sheets("CHECKER").Range("AS1").Value = Environ$("UserName")
    Application.AutoRecover.Time = 30
'End If
End Sub